# How to configure web.xml property file in Adobe Day CQ 5.5?

Tags: jsp, jstl, aem, jsessionid, sling

I work with CMS Adobe Day CQ 5.5. When I use jstl tag c:url and at the same time I turn off cookies in my browser, jsessionid parameter adds to links. There is the problem on dispatcher side when pages are cached. Surfing internet I have found solution how to prevent this behavior. For Tomcat 7 I have to add settings in web.xml file.

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

In CQ 5.4 this file is located on `/crx-quickstart/server/etc/web.xml` path. But in CQ 5.5 it doesn't exist anymore. Does anyone know how I can configurate this property in CQ 5.5?

Answer (score 0):

I watched this documentation [CQ 5.5 Release: Changes in Installation & Configuraton](http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/cq55prerelease-installandconfigchanges.html) (the part "How to start WAR deployment as publish instance?"), and as I understood, you should have a single **WAR** file for Web Application Server deployments, not JAR.

Various versions of files (JAR and WAR) are also mentioned on the page [Upgrading to CQ 5.5](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/deploying/upgrading.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running CQ5.5 and later from its Quickstart runnable jar file, it uses its own CQSE servlet engine to provide the OSGi HttpService, via the `cqse-httpservice` OSGi bundle.

That HTTP service is configurable via the OSGi console (config PID=`org.apache.felix.http`) but I don't think it provides session tracking options. If you really need this you might need to run CQ as a war file under Tomcat instead, or ask your tech support contact if there's another way.

Note that using HTTP sessions is usually not needed with Sling and CQ, unless they are required for legacy systems.